# How to use linq to compare only the same day, but in my tale filed only have time type field

Tags: c#, linq

bArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

```
canberraTimetable = (from r in db.ShuttleTimeTables
                     where r.TimeTypeId == 5 && (DateTime.Today.Date + r.Time ) >= (DateTime.Today.Date + time_15)
                     select r.Time).ToList()
                     .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                     {
                         Text = x.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm"),
                         Value = x.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm")
                     }).Take(3).ToList();
```

If I don't have `DateTime.Today.Date` add to the `r.Time` then won't have problems.
But it when the `time_15 = 23:59`, then will select the 8:00 available to the user, I don't won't this. So I add `DateTime.Today.Date` to it only arrow compare at the same day.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it,I put my answer here hope that will help some else:

```
 canberraTimetable = db.ShuttleTimeTables.Where(r => r.TimeTypeId == 5).ToList()
                                            .Where(r => (DateTime.Today.Date + r.Time) >= (DateTime.Today.Date + time_15))
                                            .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                                            {
                                                Text = x.Time.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm"),
                                                Value = x.Time.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm")
                                            }).Take(3).ToList();
```